Raycast2D.collider not null, even tho Debug.Ray clearly showing othervise
Debug.DrawRay and console:

I have a script for an enemy, that moves left and right, and when close to a wall, moves in another direction.
This is the part of the script that handles Raycasts, in Update
timer += Time.deltaTime;
Debug.Log("Right is " + right);
Debug.Log("Left is " + left);
if (timer > 1f)
{
    raycastHitLeft = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.y), new Vector2(-2, 0));
    Debug.DrawRay(new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), new Vector3 (-2, 0, 0), Color.red, 1f);
    raycastHitRight = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(transform.position.x + 1, transform.position.y), new Vector2(2, 0));
    Debug.DrawRay(new Vector3(transform.position.x + 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), new Vector3(2, 0, 0), Color.blue, 1f);
    timer = 0;

    Debug.Log("Raycast fired!");
}

I tried moving the starting position of a raycast away form the enemy, in case this would cause problems. And quadruple checked that all walls have box colliders, and that there arent any random colliders anywere.

nothing here seems to say its found a null - did you forget to tell us something?

@BugFinder the "Right/Left raycast hitted somthing" in console means that right/leftRaycastHit != null. Sorry for not providing this information

yes but the code does not produce those messages - so perhaps your logic is incorrect.

Please add the code responsible for printing the "Right/Left raycast hit something". Also to debug better you could print(raycastHit.collider.name) to show what's being hit.

The distance of both raycasts are set to Infinity.  Set the distance to the distance you expect.

@hijinxbassist i noticed this and fixed it yesterday. thank you tho
